# php : calendar script not work good in July

Tags: php, datetime, calendar

Here is my problem
all months start from day 1 
but month 7 2012 
start from day 2
don't know why

and here is the code

```
<table>
<?php
$cMonth = 7;
$cYear = 2012;

$first_day_timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday              = date("t",$first_day_timestamp);
$thismonth           = getdate($first_day_timestamp);
$startday            = $thismonth['wday'] - 1;

for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {

    if (($i % 7) == 0 )  echo "<tr>";

    if ($i < $startday) { echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>" ; continue; }

    $current_day = $i - $startday + 1;

    echo "<td>". $current_day . "</td>";

    if (($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Image attached

[image: Calendar]

Please tell me why this happened

Comment: Are you sure this isn't happening to other months?  It seems like it would.

Comment: Yes it happen in some months not all monthes
you can try the code on your localhost
it work fine for many months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing this:

```
$startday            = $thismonth['wday'] - 1;
```

??

You're moving the day offset back one.  This is effectively saying the day you want to start counting on is one day before the first day of the month.

--EDIT--
So you're doing that because you want the calendar to start on Monday instead of Sunday.  php's wday is [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php):

> 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

You're subtracting one from it will shift the start of the month down one day until and unless the month starts on Sunday.  Then $startday is -1 and it throws off your counting. You need it  to wrap around to the previous week instead.  If you add another line that fixes this case like:

```
$startday = thismonth['wday'] - 1;
if($startday < 0 ) $startday = 6;
```

It should fix the problem.  I'm sure there's other ways to compensate for Monday being the first day of the week though.

Comment: this is because calendar start from Monday
when i removed -1 it start from 1 ok but not vaild day in computer calendar

Comment: See my edit.  You have to wrap around to start on the previous saturday for months that start on a sunday because php considers sunday the first day of the week.

Answer (score 2):

Changing `$startday = $thismonth['wday'] - 1;` to `$startday = $thismonth['wday'];` displays the proper calendar with Sunday being the first day of the week.

The issue with your code is that $startday is -1 ($thismonth['wday'] is 0 since the month begins on a Sunday). In the first iteration of the loop, `$current_day = 0 - (-1) + 1 = 2` so it starts at 2, which is correct, because Monday is the 2nd of the month.

You'll have this issue on any month that begins on a Sunday. Try September 2013.

Comment: Yes it happened in sep 2012 too , but when i canged this code
`$startday = $thismonth['wday'] - 1;` to `$startday = $thismonth['wday']; `  this effect other months

Comment: How exactly does it affect the other months? It seems to work fine for me. If you want to make it start on Monday, you can set the startDay to 6 (Sunday) if it is less than 0 inside the loop.